# Mac OS Mojave - Location of system .condarc file

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I recently installed miniconda3 and am trying to locate the system .condarc file.  I am troubleshooting a problem where the default miniconda3 installation has setup 2 channels for `envs_dirs`.  I tried to remove one of the channels by running the following command:

```
conda config --system --remove envs_dirs '/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/4.6.14/miniconda3/envs'
```

However, I get this error:

> CondaKeyError: 'envs_dirs': key 'envs_dirs' is not in the config file

Running the below command shows the `envs_dirs` with both channels:

```
conda config --show
```

If I can at least locate the default system .condarc file that the Conda documentation mentions, I can possibly modify the file direct to remove it. Where should I be able to find this file?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the system condarc file specifically? Probably the setting is in the default file, i.e., `~/.condarc`

Comment: I am trying to debug an issue whereby the creation of a new environment in Miniconda3 is placing it in the first of two paths defined by `envs_dirs` which is not where I want it.  It is the 2nd path that I want it in.  Note, I do not have a `~/.condarc` file.

Comment: So on my system, running `conda config --get envs_dirs` results in no output, while `conda config --show` shows some values for `envs_dirs`. So I assume this is somehow built-in to Miniconda. However, if you add a value for `envs_dirs`, that should take priority if you use the `--add` key, as in `conda config --add envs_dirs <path-to-your-dir>`

Comment: @darthbith I added the value of the 2nd path per your suggestion and it was successful!  Interesting behavior since it did not add a duplicate 3rd path but just moved the added 2nd path as the first in the list for `envs_dirs` rather than creating a duplicate.  Not sure why for now, but I'm good with the outcome so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a shot in the dark, but try `conda info`?

While this alluded to a "user config file" at `/Users/username/.condarc` that did not exist, it also showed me a "populated config files" at `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/.condarc` which did exist and corresponded to the results from `conda config --show channels` as well.